# Is the beard on Toshiro Mifune's samurai characters an exception?

Tags: character, historical-accuracy, japanese-cinema, akira-kurosawa

I'm not sure whether historically samurai — members of the Japanese warrior caste — were supposed to always be clean-shaven or not. But I seem to recall that samurai characters in film are mostly beardless.

How exceptional is it for samurai characters *in Japanese [Jidaigeki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jidaigeki) films* (period dramas) to have beards? And is it typically some particular type of samurai characters to have them (e.g. evil vs good, old vs young, sophisticated vs plain)?

Comment: Sounds more like a question about Japanese history than movies & TV.  I'm not aware of any rules regarding facial hair for samurai, but I'm far from an expert on the subject.

Comment: @Steve-O: See edit; hopefully it makes the question for apprioriate for this venue.

Comment: Is Toshiro Mifune a Japanese filmmaker?  Perhaps editing the question to center around the specific character you are referring to rather than _all_ samurai in movies would not make the question "too broad"

Comment: @user22792: No, he's an actor. And - I am asking about Samurai characters in Japanese films in general. I don't think that's too broad.

Comment: Okay.  I didn't vote to close the question, I was just trying to help your question so that the close votes would be removed :)

Comment: @user22792: I hope my edit narrowed it down a bit.

Comment: Sure.  I think that it's fine.  I gave it an up vote now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's a good article](https://www.tofugu.com/japan/japanese-mustache/) on the topic. Most samurai were supposed to actually let their facial hair grow to show their "fighting spirit". Those with poor facial hair even got fake facial hair to avoid being mocked. Their lack of beard depiction in films is probably more because of modern Japanese ideas on beards

Comment: **If it were true. I don't think it is.** Guy in _Rashomon_ had a beard, guys in _King Lear Goes to Japan_ have beards, almost every guy in _The Magnificent Seven Part I_ has a beard, guys in _After the Rain_ have beards... It may be that OP was confusing Yul Brenner with part of the OBC or it may be that the usually scraggily hair didn't register to them.